# Developing scheduled process in .net

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have done fair bit of R&D  on the above topic .

My requirement is that I have to process a bunch of files in a particular repository  and categorize them and dump them  to subscribed users path through ftp .

This job should be done thrice in a day .

After going through lot of info available online I found that I can achieve this either using Windows service or Scheduled Tasks . Some guys say first one is better and I also found people backing later one too . So I am confused which way to go  ?

another requirement when writing a code is that some methods which I write here need to accessed by one more tiny application which we are developing in the later stage . If I write a windows service Can I consume that service in the application which I am going to develop later .

Any suggestions will do world of good .

Answer (score 0):

If you need that your methods must be accessible to other applications just create WCF service an host it in a Windows Service. For more information how to host WCF in Windows Service look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: since my  task should run only thrice a day running a windows a all time is unnecessary right ?

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh It's problem to running Windows Service all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Quartz Scheduling Library before to host my scheduled tasks, as well as Windows. In general Quartz was easier to use, but Windows Scheduler is the built in operating system method of achieving your goal, however most auto-update systems use a Window Service to achieve this instead of using Windows Scheduler. In general I'd recommend not using Windows Scheduler and using Quartz instead.